# Can I use string(or any type) list as an argument of an event?

Tags: events, string

It`s my event.

```
event Transfer(address sender, address receiver, string[] denoms, uint256[] amounts);
```

And I view an Transfer event with watch() function, It`s the result.

```
{
  address: "0x33036fcbd3413f70fbdf771a646ab7457b26d5e1",
  args: {
    amounts: [10000, 10000],
    denoms: ["", ""],
    receiver: "0x905319c93683eb3203437d21900d9bdda487f65e",
    sender: "0xb85618eac4df82118512c3ff9eca48a61a858fdb"
  },
  blockHash: "0x894fa661c7cd4fde5de2d32b9fc8732c2a58e28e93d9c8280fa7ebd8c2ffed1f",
  blockNumber: 6291,
  event: "Transfer",
  logIndex: 0,
  removed: false,
  transactionHash: "0x61b9edbc223d71accb0a223a5d7b867782f464607a41693239964f03c1def4a3",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Maybe... a string list isn`t available as an argument.
Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. A string list ( `string[]` ) cannot be used.  But, `uint256[]` is possible.

The problem you are seeing this is because Solidity does not yet support two levels of dynamic arrays i.e., `string[]` while **it requires two levels of dynamic arrays (string is a dynamic array itself).**

If you still want to use it, you just need to add an additional experimental line at the top of your code.

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

Then in the event, provide the number of values in string[] you want to pass. 
Eg. you want to pass a string list of 2 values, so write `string[2]`

```
event Transfer(address sender, address receiver, string[2] denoms, uint256[] amounts);
```

And then fire your event like this:

```
emit Transfer(addr_sender, add_receiver, ["str1", "str2"], amnt)
```

**Note:** This is an experimental feature so it's not suggested to use it on live deployments.

Also, always try to first compile your contract on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) and then on your project.